# MySQL slots under PHP / PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, vps

I'm evaluating a migration to pdo on some hosts (VPS) but it seems to come at a price of more memory required.

Q: in php.ini, there's a setting:

```
pdo_mysql.cache_size = 2000
```

I can't find much information about it, it refers to mysql-slots, whats the purpose and maths behind? After all, the mysqld has a cache of it's own - why should pdo have one too?

regards,

//t

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This setting and feature were [removed](http://news.php.net/php.cvs/61219) (see related [diff](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/pdo_mysql/pdo_mysql.c?r1=291942&r2=291941&pathrev=291942)) due to a [bug](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47712).

Answer (score 0):

I´m not sure where you are getting that information from, but according to the [List of php.ini directives](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php) there is no such directive as `pdo_mysql.cache_size`.

Comment: In /etc/php5/cgi/php.ini, ubuntu lucid

Comment: They did exist in the older version of PHP.